# Why I Can't write in the file?

Tags: php, file, server

I have to write the information I receive from a form in a text file, and this I tested locally and it worked.

```
$file = "data.txt";
$data = @fopen($file, "a");
//$data = @fopen("data.txt", "a");
@fwrite($data, "Number: " . $number . " |");
@fwrite($data, " Tittle: " . $tittle . " |");
```

But when I upload it to the server, the data is not written to the file. 
I have tried with this:

```
$data = @fopen("registers/data.txt", "a");
$data = fopen("registers/data.txt", "a");
$datos = fopen("./registers/data.txt", "a");
```

And nothing works.

In download.php I download the file and it does download correctly but without any information.

```
<?php
$file = "data.txt";

if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");

$type = filetype($file);
// Get a date and timestamp

// Send file headers
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=data.txt");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header('Expires: 0');
// Send the file contents.
set_time_limit(0); 
readfile($file);
?>
```

What can I do? I can't find a solution. Help me!

Comment: didi you try to check file permissions ?

Comment: Suggest using [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) instead and do not use `@` for error suppression - errors are important..

Answer (score 0):

When `fopen` can't open the file, it returns false and a warning is emitted. 
You can show warnings by using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your script.

Your issue is probably related to file permissions. Make sure the webserver has write permissions to the file and its directory.